# ¿Como puedo saber cuando la SKScene esta totalmente cargada para hacer un pantalla de "cargando.."?

Tags: ios, swift2, swift

La escena ejecuta todas las funciones, pero en equipos antiguos (como el 4S o el 5C) se demoran en aparecer los nodos unos 2 segundos (a veces un poco más o un poco menos)

Yo imprimo:

```
print("antes")
//sprites y matrixSprites son SKSpriteNode
sprites.addChild(matrixSprites)
print("después")
```

Se imprimen en consola los dos `print` pasan 2 segundos y recién se muestran en pantalla los elementos que están en el nodo `sprites`. Hay alguna forma de hacer una pre-carga de la escena y saber si es que en la escena ya están visibles todos los elementos, como para hacer una pantalla de "cargando...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar **SKActions** para luego utilizar **completion**, me explico en código:

```
print("antes")

let render = SKAction.run({
     sprites.addChild(matrixSprites)
})

self.run(render, completion: {
    print("después")
})
```

La idea de esto es dejar definida una acción dentro de la variable "render", esta se ejecutará por el método self.run (SKScene.run) y una vez esté completamente ejecutado entonces ejecutará las sentencias de código que definas, en el caso del ejemplo un print("respués")